# Angularjs ng-if stop rendering div

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm learning AngularJS and I want to enclose a `div` inside another one *only* when `$index == 2`.

**This is my code**:

```
<span ng-repeat="element in [0,1,2,3]">
    <div ng-if="$index == 2"> 
        <div> I'm the div
    </div>                  
    <div>
         My element: {{element}} - Index: {{$index}}
    </div>      
    <div ng-if="$index == 2"> 
        </div> I'm the /div
    </div>
</span>
```

`Fiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/2prRw/3/

**The problem**

"My element: 0", "My element: 1" and "My element: 3" are never shown.

The result is:

```
I'm the div
My element: 2 - Index: 2
I'm the /div
```

Thanks!

## Edit

The expected result is:

```
   span
     div
         My element: 0
     /div
     div
         My element: 1
     /div
     div
         div
            My element: 2
         /div
     /div
     div
         My element: 3
     /div
   /span
```

Comment: your div are not balanced right - there is missing a </div>

Comment: The missing </div> is added when $index==2 after the "<div> My element... </div>, here:  <div ng-if="$index == 2"> </div> I'm the /div </div>

Comment: this will not work - you break the dom - in every directive (like ng.if) the dom mus be complete

Comment: If you were using indentation like you should (**must**) you would never post a question with missing divs and blame ng-if.

Comment: Remember, angular still runs on JavaScript, so it doesn't "read" your HTML source file; it gets the parsed DOM from the browser itself and uses JS methods to modify things.  Your output does exactly match the expected result, given the DOM as-written in your example.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball. Now I understand the problem. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround, but which causes some duplication:

```
<span ng-repeat="element in [0,1,2,3]">
    <div ng-if="$index == 2"> 
        <div> I'm the div
            <div>
                My element: {{element}} - Index: {{$index}}
            </div>      
        </div> I'm the /div
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$index != 2">
        My element: {{element}} - Index: {{$index}}
    </div>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uJLD/1/)